# Can I make a textarea grow with text to a max height?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I'm working on a project where I have data in divs that can be various sizes. When a user clicks on one of the divs, it needs to turn into an editable textarea. The width is constant, but I'd like the height to start as the height of the original div and then grow to a max height before adding a scrollbar. Is that possible?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use `contenteditable` and let the user input in a straight `div`, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gD5jy/

### HTML

```
<div contenteditable>
    type here...
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div[contenteditable]{
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Be aware the contenteditable renders completely different HTML on different browsers, especially when it comes to line breaks.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon's right. I substituted `pre` for `div` and got the line breaking and wrapping I wanted in Chrome. When I saw his comment, I checked Firefox and ended up having to add `white-space: pre-wrap` to my CSS. I didn't try other browsers.

Comment: What if I cant use contenteditable due to React restrictions? Aaand I can't use Draft.js either because of delayed state updates.

Comment: does this contenteditable div accept any dom event? how would I capture change of the innerHTML in this div?

Comment: This is not a valid answer. A contenteditable div cannot do what a text area can.

Answer (score 8):

There's an excellent A List Apart article on this topic: [Expanding Text Areas Made Elegant](http://alistapart.com/article/expanding-text-areas-made-elegant)

Comment: Thanks for the link! Great article. I think you should at least explain in a couple of sentences how the author does it - to give readers some context before they click the link. Otherwise your post would be better as a comment according to Stack Overflow etiquette. Also, to save people time debugging, I needed to change `container.className += "active";` to `container.className += " active";` to get the author's code working.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the JavaScript function

```
// TextArea is the Id from your textarea element
// MaxHeight is the maximum height value
function textarea_height(TextArea, MaxHeight) {
    textarea = document.getElementById(TextArea);
    textareaRows = textarea.value.split("\n");
    if(textareaRows[0] != "undefined" && textareaRows.length < MaxHeight) counter = textareaRows.length;
    else if(textareaRows.length >= MaxHeight) counter = MaxHeight;
    else counter = 1;
    textarea.rows = counter; }
```

here is the css style

```
.textarea {
height: auto;
resize: none; }
```

and here is the HTML code

```
<textarea id="the_textarea" onchange="javascript:textarea_height(the_textarea, 15);" width="100%" height="auto" class="textarea"></textarea>
```

it works fine for me

Comment: What if the `textarea` contains no newlines, just wrapping?

Comment: i just copied this code from an older project... but it's possible to change the code to your needs... mabye you can split the code every 40 signs

Comment: Bad solution. What if user doesn't use enter?

Comment: Worked for me, with little change in my case. 

 function ResizeTextBox(elm)
    {
        var rowcount = $(elm).attr('rows');
        var textareaRows = $(elm).val().split("\n");

        if (textareaRows[0] != "undefined" && textareaRows.length < rowcount - 1) {
            counter = rowcount;
        }
        else {
            counter = textareaRows.length + 1;
        }
        $(elm).attr('rows', counter)
    }

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I founded ([on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement#autogrowing_textarea_example)) with Javascript and adapted to be used in one line and with a bit of style.

*The separate Javascript is only useful for automatic writing for the demo.*

```js
/*
      AUTO TYPE TEXT FROM THIS S.O. ANSWER: 
          https://stackoverflow.com/a/22710273/4031083
          Author @Mr.G
*/
var demo_input = document.getElementById('txtArea');

var type_this = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed blandit turpis, eu auctor arcu.\r\n\r\nCras iaculis urna non vehicula volutpat. Nullam tincidunt, ex sit amet commodo pulvinar, lorem ex feugiat elit, non eleifend nisl metus quis erat.";
var index = 0;

window.next_letter = function() {
    if (index <= type_this.length) {
        demo_input.value = type_this.substr(0, index++);
        demo_input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup'));
        setTimeout("next_letter()", 50);
    }
}

next_letter();
```

```html
<!-- THE MAIN PART -->
<textarea 
  id = "txtArea"
  cols="20" 
  rows="4" 
  onkeyup="if (this.scrollHeight > this.clientHeight) this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 'px';"
  style="overflow:hidden;
         transition: height 0.2s ease-out;">
         
</textarea>
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the user wants to edit what he just typed and starts adding lines at the start of the text. Since scroll won't be higher than height.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is fairly old, but a trick that I have used to dynamically scale `textarea` is to check if the `scrollTop` of the `textarea` element is more than zero since that would mean that it's scrollable. In the event that it's scrollable, simply increment the rows in a `while` loop while the `scrollTop` is more than zero...

```
if(textarea.scrollTop>0){
            while(textarea.scrollTop>0){
                textarea.rows++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Old post but it's the top result on google, so let me share my simple answer.

I just make a function that runs every 200ms, updating the textarea. It's a very easy way to do it, but it works for me.

***Ignore the css please! It is just for decoration.***

```js
function textarea_height() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById("htmlinput");
  textarea.rows = textarea.value.split("\n").length;
}
setInterval(textarea_height, 200);
```

```css
#htmlinput {
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border-width: 3.3px;
  font-family: monospace;
  background-color:lightgray;
  width: calc(98%);
  padding: 5.5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> StackOverflowExample </title>
</head>
<body>

  <textarea id="htmlinput">Here is my
  Very Cool
  Text Area
  it even fits
  to the lines of
  the text!</textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will work, however this is not good approach.