# Auto type inside text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to let there automatically appear text inside an input type=text element.

I would like to accomplish that the different kind of texts are stored inside an array and that every 5 seconds or so, a text is 'typed' by javascript into this field. Then I also like that when I focus on the field (to input text in it by keyboard) that it stops auto-typing and shows an empty input element.

Anybody know how to go about this?
I'm a back-end programmer, but need to do some frontend programming and just haven't had the time to thoroughly learn Javascript. At the moment I only know PHP thoroughly, but would expand my knowledge to css, html and javascript too.

Hope somebody is able to help me out :)

**EDIT: This is the solution I came up with and it works. The input field has as ID: searchBar.** The code is not very elegant, but I'm still learning :) Thanks for the answers. It helped me a lot.

```
var searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');

var keywords = ['Auto typed text number 1',
               'This is number 2 auto typed',
               'Yet another auto typed line',
               'The last line before it loops again'];

var index = 0;
var arrCounter = 0;
var focus = false;
var timer1, timer2;

function resetBox() {
    searchBar.value = '';
    index = 0;
    autoType();
}

var autoType = function() {

    if (focus) {

        return;
    }

    if (index <= keywords[arrCounter].length) {
        searchBar.value = keywords[arrCounter].substr(0, index++);
        timer1 = setTimeout("autoType()", 50);
    } else {

        arrCounter++;
        if(arrCounter === keywords.length){
            arrCounter = 0;
        }

        timer2 = setTimeout(resetBox, 5000);
    }
};

autoType();
$("#searchBar").on("focus", function(){
    focus = true;
    searchBar.value = '';
    clearTimeout(timer1);
    clearTimeout(timer2);

}).on("blur", function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        focus = false;
        resetBox();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: no one codes for you free here ! show what you have done so far !

Comment: hire a developer or get to the basics first.

Comment: I didn't ask for a whole script that does EVERYTHING. I just needed a starting point from where I can experiment further. Mr.G pointed me in the right direction for this, that's all. I didn't mean to upset you all.

Comment: @Wcool: your question actually helped me on a problem i was working on. Kudos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try like this:**

**html**

```
<input id='demo_input' size='100'/>
```

**javascript:**

```
var demo_input = document.getElementById('demo_input');

var type_this = "try this example";
var index = 0;

window.next_letter = function() {
    if (index <= type_this.length) {
        demo_input.value = type_this.substr(0, index++);
        setTimeout("next_letter()", 50);
    }
}

next_letter();
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I only needed a starting point. Usually when I get a script I can work it out by experimenting. Thanks again.

Comment: I posted the final code now. Thanks for helping me getting on track Mr.G.